# Cognos ungroup crosstab rows

Tags: crosstab, cognos

I need to ungroup the rows in a crosstab. The package is built off of a TM1 dimensional cube.

I currently have this in the rows of the crosstab.

```
     REGION |   VP  | Managers
     South     Mark   Bill
                      Jessica
                      Mike
```

What I need is for the 'South' and 'Mark' to show up for all the rows not just the one with Bill.
I also need this to work in excel so the workaround of putting it all in one data item will not work for this. Also because it does not work with the cube the way it is built.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is doable with a bit of a workaround.
For example, let's say we have Product Line and Product Type in a crosstab, and want Product Line to repeat for each Product Type.
Bring Product Type into the rows twice, unlock the report, cut out the first Product Type text item, drag Product Line into the space, Product line should now repeat every row

If this does not work you can always press Ctl+Alt+M to access the
Cognos 10 tool bar, and go under File>Report Properties and uncheck
"Group repeating cells when exporting to Excel". Although simple, this
method is not supported by IBM and therefor they cannot be responsible if 
it affects the functionality of your Cognos install/reports/etc... You
may use it at your own risk.

Comment: This worked in Cognos 11 as well, but I had to 'Box Type->None' the original columns instead of cutting them.

Answer (score 0):

In version 11.2.1 you can find this option by clicking "**Report > Report**" and setting the option "**Group repeating cells - export to Excel**" to "**No**" in the **Properties tab**.

[image: Screenshot]